# How to sort content from a mysql table in different ways without having multiple pages?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a section on my website where users can post comments. Just above these comments I have 4 links - Oldest, Newest, Top Rated and Worst Rated. Currently I have 4 different pages for each of these links.

> oldest.php - sorts the comments by date and time ascending
>
> newest.php - sorts the comments by date and time descending
>
> top.php - sorts the comments depending on how many likes they have
>
> worst.php - sorts the comments depending on how many dislikes they
>   have

They are all being sorted with a mySQL statement such as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

I'm just wondering is there any way to order these comments by using just one page instead of having 4 different pages?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you pass the sort column and direction in the URL.

```
$type = 'new'; // default order
$cols = array('old', 'new', 'worst'); // array with possible options columns, to prevent SQL injection
if (in_array($_GET['type'], $cols) {
    $type = $_GET['type'];
}
$order = (strtolower($_GET['order']) == 'asc')?'ASC':'DESC'; // again - to prevent bad data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY {$type} {$order}, time DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

If you have different queries, just use a `switch()` statement, and change the query accordingly for each type of order.

```
// use the same order as before
switch ($_GET['type']):
case 'old':
     $sql = " ... ";
break;

// more options
default:
    // default can be used for the most common option, for example when you first enter the page with no type argument in the URL
break;
```

One more thing - to generate the URLs you can use this:

```
$cols = array('old', 'new', 'worst'); // you can make this array a config variable
$order = array('asc', 'desc');
foreach ($cols as $col) {
    foreach ($order as $ord) {
        echo "<a href='index.php?type={$col}&order={$ord}'>".ucwords($col). ' ' . ucwords($ord)"</a>";
    }
}
```

This will print all the types with all the possible orders. You should play around with this, you can do some neat, dynamic stuff.

Comment: This option is more secure, because it's really bad practice to just include your GET request in the sql. (SQL injection)

Comment: If you check my code you will notice that the data from URL is checked against expected results, and if it doesn't comply, default values are used

Comment: I know, that's why I said your solution is the best.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! So do I then have my links looking something like this: "comments.php?type=date&order=DESC" ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Good luck with this !

Comment: Ah I just saw you added to it there! Thats brilliant, its exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for all your help Vlad!

Comment: **your answer is vulnerable  to sql injection**

Comment: Hmm, they are filtered with pre-defined values, could you possibly tell me how it's vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can have single page to manage that.

Instead of 4 pages, you can have single page

comments.php

and then you can pass GET parameter like below for 4 links

`comments.php?type=oldest

comments.php?type=newest

comments.php?type=top

comments.php?type=worst`

Then on `comments.php` you can put conditional statement like below:

```
$order_by = "ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC"; // Default order
if(isset($_GET["type"]) && $_GET["type"] == "newest")
    $order_by = "ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";
elseif(isset($_GET["type"]) && $_GET["type"] == "oldest")
    $order_by = "ORDER BY date, time";
elseif(isset($_GET["type"]) && $_GET["type"] == "top")
    ... put your order by here ...
elseif(isset($_GET["type"]) && $_GET["type"] == "worst")
    ... put your order by here ...
```

Then use below $sql

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ".$order_by." LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";